# Junit5 - ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy - How to?

Tags: junit5

I found the [Junit5 docu](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/index.html#writing-tests-parallel-execution-config) that with `ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy` it is possible to implement ones own strategy. I search but didn't find valid samples.

My main issue is that I have in the tested classes a `ThreadLocal` which requires for each test an own (new) Thread. Is there a working sample how to provide this?

My current workaround is to set `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.dynamic.factor=100` which is not really the way I thought things are intended to work.